# Drupal Views, Taxonomy

Tags: drupal, url, view, taxonomy, aliases

We are using Taxonomy and Views modules to display content based on the taxonomy item(s) selected. So, when users click on the taxonomy terms,on the menu, the views block picks the URL and based on that URL figures what city/term has been chosen, however, the problem with this method is that we need to always have this URL pattern: "home/city/city-name", so that the views argument could recognize the city, and this happens by passing the second part of the URL(city) to the views argument and it check if it equals to "city" then use the third part of the URL (City-name) as the city name, and then we use that to know what city has been selected... so does anyone know of any other method to do this ?

any help would be highly appreciated :)

Thanks,
Kourosh

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [pathauto module](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) which will allow you to create all kinds of path aliases.